# Change main domain name in cPanel

Tags: domains, cpanel, add-on-domain

Is it possible to change main domain name? I added a new domain name as addon domain, but the problem now is that the site isn't working on the new domain but when I enter the existing, there shows a root to the new domain name and only this way I can enter it. But now I just want to enter the new domain name and enter the site.

Comment: Does the new "addon" domain point to the document root (like a cPanel "parked domain") or to a subdirectory? It would be more usual to create a "parked" domain for this purpose. However, to completely "change the main domain", ie. change the domain that your account is associated with you'll need to talk to your host.

Answer (score 2):

Because the main domain name must be set as the base domain for all services for a host, to change it requires a reconfiguration of the base domain. This can only be accomplished with root server access. On a shared host that means contacting support. Depending on the service provider they may require a small payment to do this.

To apply a second domain name to the same server by which people can access the same website as accessed through the primary domain name requires you adding the alternative domain as a parked domain, pointing at the root domain. Whereas, an add-on domain is a process to allow an additional domain to operate as a separate website on the same server, and this process creates a subdirectory and points the add-on domain at that directory. (A sub-domain is similar to this except it uses the primary domain and a prefix other than www, and the prefix will be the same as the subdirectory that is created.)

It is a strange error that has resulted from the add-on domain - I suspect that the subdirectory name or file that was created for the add-on domain has either affected the structure or over-written the alias for the root www directory.

Either way, **remove the add-on domain, check that the primary domain is working correctly again, and then add the secondary domain as a parked domain** and this will resolve the issue.